# NLTK Texttiling

Tags: python, nltk

I want to divide some texts into subtopics. I found texttiling algorithm implemented in Python by NLTK. The problem I have is that instead of returning text tile, it returns the same text I feed as input.

```
corpus_root = 'C:/path/to/text/file'
wordlists = PlaintextCorpusReader(corpus_root, ['file.txt'])
praw = wordlists.raw('file.txt')

ttt = nltk.tokenize.TextTilingTokenizer()
tiles = ttt.tokenize(praw)
```

So instead of getting a list of tiles, I get a list with one entry which is the entire text from file.txt.

I also tried to load the text file with python methods and I get the same result.

```
file = open("file.txt")
lines = file.read()

ttt = nltk.tokenize.TextTilingTokenizer()
tiles = ttt.tokenize(lines)
```

Does anybody have any idea why the text is not segmented?

Thanks.

Comment: I solved this by replacing the newlines in the input text by double new lines, i.e. if input text was "foo\nbar", I changed it to "foo\n\nbar" and suddenly the paragraphs were found correctly. I debugged the tokenizer method and played around with it. Documentation on this is insufficient. Good luck ;)

Comment: It works. Thanks @keltomat